# Wait in angular until elements are loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular we have an enrich method which runs some rest call to enrich a data object, then sets a variable which will cause a hidden details tab to be visible.  Something like this overly simplified example:

```
$scope.enrich = function(team){
    angular.forEach(team.members, function(member){
        member.getSkills().then(function(skills){
            member.skills=skills;
        }
    });

    $scope.enrichFinished=true;
};
```

I'm getting exceptions in the detail pane which is opened when enrichFinished is true.  The exceptions appear to be due to a filter which attempts to filter on member.skill and discovers skill is undefined for the member.  I assume the problem is that we open the detail tab as soon as enrichFinished is set, which is before the then clause that sets member.skills=skill; thus we have a datarace where skills's may not yet be set by the time we try to filter on it.

What is the cleanest way to tell angular to wait to run the filter in the detail's tab until after I have actually generated and saved the data I need?  The actual enrich method enriches 3-4 different variables within the for loop.

Comment: you need set `enrichFinished` after all promisses solve, so `$q.all` possibly helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `$scope.enrichFinished=true;` after all promisses solve, so you can use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) like this

```
$scope.enrich = function(team){
    $q.all(team.members.map(
                function(member){
                    return member.getSkills().then(
                        function(skills){
                            member.skills=skills;
                        }
                    );                        
                }
            )
    ).then(function(){
        $scope.enrichFinished=true;
    });
};
```